# What documents does a Type C UK Visa holder need to travel to Belgium?

Tags: schengen, europe, exchange, study, belgium

I'm travelling to Belgium in April. I need to apply for a Schengen Visa. Doing that via Belgium.

I am an Indian Citizen, in UK at the moment, on a university exchange program on a Type C Short term visa. I want to visit a friend in Belgium for a week in April. My UK visa expires in July. I have my appointment with the Belgian Embassy in 4 days.

I have the following documents:

1. A letter from my university addressed to the Belgian Embassy regarding my association with college.
2. A Travel Insurance for my stay.

My questions:

1. How do I show what money I have? I have money in my home currency INR. Do I need to transfer this into pounds first? To show the embassy I have money? I have 450 GBP in my forex card and 300 GBP in the bank at the moment. The rest of my money is in INR.
2. Do emails/pdfs count as valid bank documents?
3. I must carry a letter from my friend stating that I will be staying with them. Will an email from him to me suffice? What is the format of this email?
4. Any other documents I might need?

Comment: You need a Schengen Visa.
But it sounds as if you are already applying for one.
Do you mean to ask what documents you should take with you to your visa interview?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry for not mentioning that at all

Comment: 2)No 3)Need paper one in original. And why don't you contact VFS, presumably they are the agents.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How do I show what money I have?

According to [immihelp](http://www.immihelp.com/visas/schengenvisa/documents.html):

[image: TSE64630 first example]

> 1. I have money in my home currency INR. Do I need to transfer this into pounds first?

No.

> 1. To show the embassy I have money?  I have 450 GBP in my forex card and 300 GBP in the bank at the moment. The rest of my money is in INR.

According to [immihelp](http://www.immihelp.com/visas/schengenvisa/means-of-substinence.html) Belgium expects access to at least €50/day for those living in hotel accommodation and €38/day for those staying with a private individual. For a week £750 is sufficient.

> 2. Do emails/pdfs count as valid bank documents?

No, these should be originals or certified copies.

> 3. I must carry a letter from my friend stating that I will be staying with them. Will an email from him to me suffice?

No. The requirement is for a letter.

> 3. What is the format of this email?

N/A.

> 4. Any other documents I might need?

In all, the following:

[Belgium visa application documentary requirements for students](http://www.schengenvisainfo.com/belgium-visa/)

•   Firstly, download the application form, fill it completely and with sincerity. You can also fill the Schengen Visa application form electronically and then print a hard-copy.

•   2 photos must be attached; the photo should be of passport format – a recent whole-face capture with a light background. Learn more about photo requirements and specifications for a Belgian Visa.

•   Your passport and copies of your previous visas – valid for at least 3 months beyond return date – are required. Your passport must have at least two blank pages.

•   Travel health insurance confirmation of minimum 30,000 € coverage within Belgium and the entire Schengen area.

•   A cover letter stating the purpose of visit to Belgium and itinerary.

•   Flight Itinerary with dates and flight numbers specifying entry and exit from Belgium.

[immihelp](http://www.immihelp.com/visas/schengenvisa/means-of-substinence.html) adds:

[image: TSE64630 second example]

but I think (a) other types of ticket would serve (eg bus, ferry or  train) and 'return' does not have to be to home country.

•   Hotel Booking for the whole duration of the intended stay in Belgium.

•   Proof of civil status (marriage certificate, birth certificate of children, death certificate of spouse, ration card if applicable)

•   Means of subsistence – Proof of sufficient financial means for the period of stay

•   Invitation letter with the address and phone number from family member or sponsor – if applicable.

•   Bank statement of the last 6 months.

•   Passport copies.

•   Proof of enrollment.

•   No-objection certificate from school or university.

The above are expressed as "requirements" but clearly not all are really required. In some cases alternatives will serve (eg if the letter of invitation includes the offer of accommodation a hotel booking should not be necessary) so it is really a matter of taking the above into consideration and trying to provide as many of the above, or equivalents, as seems appropriate. Whatever you do or do not provide by way of a little more or a little less may make all the difference but on the other hand may make no difference.